# Amazon EventBridge - how to measure non matched event?

Tags: aws-event-bridge

As I understand all unmatched events in Amazon EventBridge will expire after 24 hours. So how can we count them to make sure that my events are not lost and all matched
For example if producer changes schema and it stops matching rule pattern as a result - how can I setup some sort of alarm of DLQ for such events?

Hope that make sense,

Regards,
Max

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

You can set up DLQ as an EventBridge target. They are standard SQS queque which you can use to track and count undelivered message. You can receive notifications when events are moved to a DLQ from CloudWatch Alarms. There are some already discussions here you can try [Configure SQS Dead letter Queue to raise a cloud watch alarm on receiving a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211243/configure-sqs-dead-letter-queue-to-raise-a-cloud-watch-alarm-on-receiving-a-mess)

Comment: DLQ helps gather failed events. Not unmatched ones.