# SQS get number of messages sent to a dead letter queue within a given period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a dead-letter queue which receives messages as a result of a failed processing attempt from Lambda function. In this case, the `NumberOfMessagesSent` metric for the dead-letter queue [is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60601778/1718159). Therefore I found a way to derive this Cloudwatch metric from `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` using a metric math like:

```
IF(DIFF(mDLQApproxNumberOfMessagesVisible) > 0, DIFF(mDLQApproxNumberOfMessagesVisible), 0)
```

This gave me the possibility to see how many messages were sent to the DLQ on a minutely basis:

[image]

What I want to do is to create a second metric `eDLQNumberOfMessagesSentPerHour` that will show me the total number of received messages within 1 hour.

Adding a second expression with `SUM([eDLQNumberOfMessagesSent])` and `period: 3600` does not work.

Full example:

```
{
    "metrics": [
        ["AWS/SQS", "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible", "QueueName", "dlq.fifo", {
            "id": "mDLQApproxNumberOfMessagesVisible",
            "visible": false
        }],
        [{
            "expression": "IF(DIFF(mDLQApproxNumberOfMessagesVisible) > 0, DIFF(mDLQApproxNumberOfMessagesVisible), 0)",
            "label": "eDLQNumberOfMessagesSent",
            "id": "eDLQNumberOfMessagesSent",
            "period": 60,
            "stat": "Maximum"
        }],
        [{
            "expression": "SUM([eDLQNumberOfMessagesSent])",
            "label": "eDLQNumberOfMessagesSentPerHour",
            "id": "eDLQNumberOfMessagesSentPerHour",
            "period": 3600,
            "stat": "Sum"
        }]
    ],
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "stat": "Maximum",
    "period": 60
}
```